# Twilio php Library SDK 5 curl response body to get sid

Tags: php, sms, twilio, message

I am creating my own message logging when sending and receiving messages from/to twilio via the PHP REST api sdk 5.  I want to get the message sid when sending a new message and digging around in the code I found I can get it from 
Twilio\Http\CurlClient.php
line 36 starts:

```
36           list($head, $body) = ($parts[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue')
37                              ? array($parts[1], $parts[2])
38                               : array($parts[0], $parts[1]);
```

I added line 39

```
39          $GLOBALS["curlResponseBody"] = $body;
```

so I can retrieve the json response which has an entry for 'sid' of the message just created.

There has go to be a method for getting that information but I just haven't seen it mentioned anywhere in respect to SDK5.
Here is the code I am using to create the message:

```
require_once 'Twilio/autoload.php'; // Loads the library
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);

$client->messages->create(
    $toPhone,
    array(
        'from' => $fromTwilioPhone,
        'body' => $responseMessage,
    )
);

//This edit to the Twilio PHP Library is found in Twilio\Http\CurlClient.php            
$curlResponseBody = json_decode($GLOBALS["curlResponseBody"]);
$newMessageSid = $curlResponseBody->sid;
```

Is there some way to use $client to get to the 'sid' of the message just created?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The `create()` function returns an object that should let you get the message sid:

```
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);

$msg = $client->messages->create(
    $toPhone,
    array(
        'from' => $fromTwilioPhone,
        'body' => $responseMessage,
    )
);

echo $msg.Sid
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I found $msg.Sid was causing a failure but $msg.sid (lowercase) did produce a text piece like:   [Twilio.Api.V2010.MessageInstance accountSid=****************** sid=SMdeeb8d9d10ab463a94f8ba081d60871d]  which is really close to what I want and could parse out the sid value.  Is this what you were expecting it to produce?  It really is a big help.

Comment: sorry, try `$msg->sid`